# Javascript - correct way to remove an event listener?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an answer in plain, vanilla javascript if possible. I know the use of plain javascript and var, etc is old school but this is the code I have to work with.

I have 2 variables. `randomQ` is an object with has a few properties including `.correct`. My other variable, `answerChoice` is a nodelist of 4 `<li>` elements in an HTML file. In my function, I set the text content of each `li` element. I then create an event listener for them. When the user clicks one of the `li` elements, I want to reset the text content. But before I reset the text content, I need to remove the event listener using `.removeEventListener()`. This is where I am struggling.

Where/How should I remove an event listener?

Here is my code as is, with comments to hopefully clarify things

```
var answerChoice = document.querySelectorAll(".answer-choice");    //this is a nodelist of 4 HTML elements


function evaluateUserChoice(randomQ) {
// takes random question created from makeQuestion()
// evaluates if user clicks on correct answer or not

for (var i = 0; i < answerChoice.length; i++) {
    answerChoice[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var element = event.target;
        //checking to see if user choice is correct
        if (element.textContent === randomQ.correct) {
            score++;
            numberCorrect.textContent = score;
            answerChoice[i].removeEventListener("click",);   // is this where I remove an event listener?
            makeQuestion()                      // resets text content of HTML
        } else {
            answerChoice[i].removeEventListener("click",);    //is this where I remove an event listener?
            makeQuestion();                     // resets text content of HTML
        }    
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You need to remember the function you used with `addEventListener`, then use that same function with `removeEventListener`. Example (and alternative, since you don't need to recreate that function every time): https://pastebin.com/bvSET7wM

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand better what you are trying to do. However, after trying your pastebin code I still can't make it work.  In your first example, I get "cannot read property of removeEventListener of undefined".  In the second example I get an error in the choiceClickHandler function that it randomQ is undefined. I cannot pass an argument to a callback function. 

What else can I do?

Comment: Sorry about that: https://pastebin.com/zNSsGmuJ In the first solution, `i` also needed to be declared with `let` rather than `var` (or better yet, grab `answerChoice[i]` to a local `const` and reuse it). In the second, I hadn't noticed that you needed the handler to close over `randomQ`, so I moved the handler declaration into `evaluateUserChoice`.

Comment: thank you @T.J.Crowder